# Create and Update AWS Event Bus using SDK

Tags: c#, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I would like to create a web api project to allow the following in code using the AWS SDK (C# or Python):

1. Create an event bus
2. Update an event bus properties like Schedule, Rules and Target to a lambda function

I am using the documentation here as reference.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/EventBridge/TEventBridgeClient.html

I would appreciate any guidance on how to go about doing this and if there are already resources out there that can achieve the same.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Schedule, Rules and Target are not *properties* of an event bus. [create_event_bus](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#EventBridge.Client.create_event_bus) and [put_rule](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#EventBridge.Client.put_rule) are what you need. Not sure what more you need, just play around with them.

Comment: @luk2302, thank you very much for the response. The links will help a lot.